# How to implement a sequence of consecutive operations using rxJava?

Tags: rx-java

I have the download process that consists of 3 consecutive operations: `preProcess`, `downloading`, `postProcess`. Each operation has asynchronous nature (`preProcess` calls API, `downloading` waits file to be downloaded etc). UI have to display which operations is executing (eg. "preparing...", "downloading...", "unpacking...").
I see whole process as `Observable` that emits current status of whole operation. Each operation is also an observable, that emits his status in the start of executions and completes after execution.

```java
    Observable.OnSubscribe<DownloadStatus>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super DownloadStatus> subscriber) {
            subscriber.onNext(DownloadStatus.PRE_PROCESS);
            doPreProcess()
                    .subscribe(new Action1<File>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(File file) {
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

    Observable<DownloadStatus> mDonwloadingOperation = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<DownloadStatus>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super DownloadStatus> subscriber) {
            subscriber.onNext(DownloadStatus.DOWNLOADING);
            doDownloading()
                    .subscribe(new Action1<File>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(File file) {
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

    Observable<DownloadStatus> mPosProcessOperation = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<DownloadStatus>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super DownloadStatus> subscriber) {
            subscriber.onNext(DownloadStatus.POST_PROCESS);
            doPostProcess()
                    .subscribe(new Action1<File>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(File file) {
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

On the one hand each operation should wait until previous operations completes. On the other hand subscriber need to receive each emitted status (eg. PRE_PROCESS -> DOWNLOADING -> POST_PROCESS -> onComplete)

I cannot use `merge` because each operation should depend on completion of previous one.
I cannot use `flatMap` because i don't know how to propagate emitted status. I think that `Subject` could be the solution, but i also don't know how to propagate emitted status.

How can I solve such problem with rxJava? Thank for any ideas/clues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`concat`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) is what you need. This subscribes to the concatenated observable once the preceding one has finished.

`concatMap` also works like `flatMap` but concatenates the flattened projections. There's a nice diagram [here](http://fernandocejas.com/2015/01/11/rxjava-observable-tranformation-concatmap-vs-flatmap/) on the difference between those two.