# How to use RxJava for asynchronously executing a dynamic list of consecutive dependent operations?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I'm working on an Android Service Library (AAR) that has to execute a variable number of processes consecutive/pipelined on an input (JSON) in the background.

Thereby, the next process takes the output of the previous process as input.

The processes can involve literally every kind of possibly long running tasks (http requests, IO/DB requests, heavy data crunching, ...)

It shall be possible to log the progress between every process and get the final output of the last process e.g. in a subscriber (library service thread).

The processes should run stable, in case internet connection is lost or parent application state is changing.
I'm currently using [Robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) in my library to achieve stability for multiple requests...

This question: [How to implement a sequence of consecutive operations using rxjava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407059/how-to-implement-a-sequence-of-consecutive-operations-using-rxjava)
is related to my question, except I ask for a variable sequence of operations.

Is it possible achieve this with Rxjava? If yes, how? If not, what are other options?

My idea how to do it somehow without Rxjava:

- Keep Process count for every request
- Processes[counter].execute(result, callback)
- Callback-OnSuccess(result): increase process counter and start Processes[counter] with result

But I'm not experienced with thread handling and think this is not very robust and maybe it doesn't even work or blocks the calling thread (what makes the library not usable for this time)

Comment: did you see http://stackoverflow.com/q/36639458/309483 ? If all your Observables return JSON and consume JSON, it is possible to fold over the Oberservables and pair them like in the linked answer.

Comment: Thank you @JanusTroelsen this could actually work.